# Delete user's manager in Azure through REST api

Tags: java, azure, office365-restapi

I'm able to assign user's manager through REST API using:

```
 PUT https://graph.windows.net/{userid}/users//$links/manager?api-version=2013-11-08
```

With body:

```
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "url": "https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/directoryObjects/fabeb27a-0481-4a80-b43e-a5c02c125874"
}
```

But how can i delete user manager? please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the offical document references for Azure AD Graph API, as below.

1. [Other navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#other-navigation-properties) for user navigation properties
2. [User Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) inherits from DirectoryObject

[image]

According to the above content, you can delete an user's manager via do a `DELETE` operation for the related directoryObject which be from the response of the operation for assignning user's manager as below.

```
DELETE https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/directoryObjects/fabeb27a-0481-4a80-b43e-a5c02c125874
```

For more details, please see the document [Delete directoryObject](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryobject_delete).